# how to use execute() in groovy to run any command

Tags: ant, groovy

I usually build my project using these two commands from command line (dos)

```
G:\> cd c:
C:\> cd c:\my\directory\where\ant\exists
C:\my\directory\where\ant\exists> ant -Mysystem
...
.....
build successful
```

What If I want to do the above from groovy instead? groovy has `execute()` method but following does not work for me:

```
def cd_command = "cd c:"
def proc = cd_command.execute()
proc.waitFor()
```

it gives error:

```
Caught: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "cd": CreateProcess error=2, The
 system cannot find the file specified
        at ant_groovy.run(ant_groovy.groovy:2)
```

Answer (score 15):

Or more explicitly, I think binil's solution should read

```
"your command".execute(null, new File("/the/dir/which/you/want/to/run/it/from"))
```

Answer (score 5):

According to this [thread](http://osdir.com/ml/lang.groovy.user/2004-09/msg00044.html) (the 2nd part), `"cd c:".execute()` tries to run a program called `cd` which is not a  program but a built-in shell command.

The workaround would be to change directory as below (not tested):

`System.setProperty("user.dir", "c:")`

Answer (score 4):

```
"your command".execute(null, /the/dir/which/you/want/to/run/it/from)
```

should do what you wanted.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Noel and Binil, I had a similar problem with a build Maven.

```
projects = ["alpha", "beta", "gamma"]

projects.each{ project ->
    println "*********************************************"
    println "now compiling project " + project
    println "cmd /c mvn compile".execute(null, new File(project)).text
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got to fix the issue by running a command as below:
i wanted to run git commands from git folder, so below is the code which worked for me.

```
println(["git","add","."].execute(null, new File("/Users/xyz/test-org/groovy-scripts/$GIT_REPOS/")).text)
        println(["git","commit","-m","updated values.yaml"].execute(null, new File("/Users/xyz/test-org/groovy-scripts/$GIT_REPOS/")).text)
        println(["git","push","--set-upstream","origin","master"].execute(null, new File("/Users/xyz/test-org/groovy-scripts/$GIT_REPOS/")).text)
```